# Why isn't the Google button showing in Akeeba social login when using Helix Ultimate Template?

Tags: angular-social-login, joomla4, akeeba

I open this post because I have a problem with akeeba social login. I successfully activated the plugin, created the client ID and Secret key credentials but the google button is not generated. I don't use the form to connect to the private area but I created access directly from the main menu link. then sign in appears in the menu bar.
The google button therefore does not appear in login or register. how can I solve this problem? I don't use the cassiopeia template but Helix Ultimate Template.
Thank you.

I tried to check if there were explanations on other sites to make the google button appear, but nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Helix3 doesn't use the onUserLoginButtons hook, while Akeeba Social Login does (it has become the standard in Joomla! since 4.0 release AFAIK).
There is another person who asked this here: https://www.joomshaper.com/forum/question/20910

From Akeeba Socail Login page: "Login buttons are rendered by Joomla itself, using the new “additional login buttons” feature introduced in Joomla 4 as part of the WebAuthn integration. SocialLogin's system plugin gathers the information from the sociallogin plugins and conveys them to Joomla through the onUserLoginButtons event. The Joomla core or third party code consuming this even is solely responsible for rendering the login buttons. [...] If you are using a third party component, such as Community Builder, to display a user profile page you will need to integrate SocialLogin into it with template overrides." (https://github.com/akeeba/sociallogin/wiki/Overview-of-the-Social-Login-system#joomla-4) and the link is to the documentation here: https://github.com/akeeba/sociallogin/wiki/Integrating-with-template-overrides
where, unfortunately, the advice is: "If your extension does not render these buttons please talk to its developer. They need to update its code for Joomla 4. There is nothing you can do with an override."

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully it seems Helix has incorporated the onUserLoginButtons
I'd upvote you marcocassisa though my account's too fresh.

Comment: please expand this into a standalone answer (see [answer])